# Fatal Error Call to member function result() - Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Seems like a common occurance this error on here, Looking at the answers I still cant quite work out why I'm getting an error.

I am getting the error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object on line **83**

The line in question relates to this function in the **Controller** - This is what's creating the error.

> $this->view_data['categories'] = $my_categories->result();

The function is below..

```
function _load_search_options()
{
    // Get all the categories for the advanced search page
    $my_categories = $this->Categories_model->get_all();
    $this->view_data['categories'] = $my_categories->result();

    // Get all the PRIMARY colours from teh tbl_colour_options
    $my_colour_options = $this->Colours_model->get_all_primary();
    $this->view_data['colour_options'] = $my_colour_options->result();


    // Get all the colours from teh tbl_colour_options
    $my_colour_options_all = $this->Colours_model->get_all();
    $this->view_data['colour_options_all'] = $my_colour_options_all->result();
}
```

My Model is as follows...

```
function get_all()
{
    $query_str = "
        SELECT *
        FROM categories
        WHERE CATEGORIES_parent_id = 0
    ";

    $results = $this->db->query($query_str);
    $parents = $results->result();

    foreach ($parents as $parent)
    {
        $children = array();

        $query_str = "
            SELECT *
            FROM categories
            WHERE CATEGORIES_parent_id = '$parent->CATEGORIES_id'
        ";

        $children_results = $this->db->query($query_str);
        $children_results = $children_results->result();

        foreach($children_results as $children_result)
        {
            $children[$children_result->CATEGORIES_id] = $children_result->CATEGORIES_title;
        }

        $categories[$parent->CATEGORIES_title] = $children;




    }

    return $categories;
}
```

It's worth noting that running the SELECT query in MySQL on its own brings through some results.

Comment: go to line 83 and type `echo gettype($my_categories)` this should answer your question

Comment: do var_dump($my_categories) to verify if is null

Comment: @khaled_webdev it is coming back with a large array of data..

Comment: CATEGORIES_parent_id it's int or string?

Comment: CATEGORIES_parent_id is set as an INT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `get_all` doesn't return a database object (resource).

The `$categories` variable in the `get_all` function is defined as an array.

You cannot access it as an object or call the `results` function.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've got a similar result set that isnt an array. Removed the array set and its working.